# Sorting column for HTML Report from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I sort the "Online" column and Uptime column? I would like to show True at the top with the longest uptime at the top, followed by FALSE.

```
    <#

    .Synopsis 
        Query Uptime Details of servers.

    .Description
        This script helps you to get the uptime details of the servers. It also generates a HTML report
        when -HTMLReport switch is used. The report contains the uptime details and a summary of how many
        computers reachable and how many are not

    .Parameter ComputerName    
        Computer name(s) for which you want to get the uptime details.

    .Parameter HTMLReport
        Generates a HTML report in c:\ drive with name uptimereport.html by default. You can override this by
        specifying -HTMLFile parameter

    .Parameter HTMLFile
        Name of the file path where you want to store the report

    .Example
        Get-UptimeOfServers.ps1 -ComputerName Comp1, Comp2

        Gets the Uptime of Comp1 and Comp2
    .Example
        Get-UptimeOfServers.ps1 -ComputerName Comp1, Comp2 -HTMLReport

        Get the uptime of Comp1 and Comp2 and saves the report in HTML format

    .Example
        Get-Content c:\servers.txt | Get-UptimeOfServers.ps1 -HTMLReport

        Get the uptime of computers listed in servers.txt and saves the report in HTML format   

    .Notes
        NAME:      Get-UptimeOfServers.ps1
        AUTHOR:    Sitaram Pamarthi
        WEBSITE:   http://techibee.com

#>

[cmdletbinding()]

param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:computername,
    [switch]$HTMLReport,
    [string]$HTMLFile = "c:\Temp\Uptimereport.html"
)

begin{
if($HTMLReport) {
    $Report = "

            <html>
                <head>
                    <title> Server Uptime Report </title>
                </head>
                <body> 

                    <H1 Align=`"Center`"> <B>Server Uptime Report </B></H1>
                    <br>
                    <H3 Align=`"Center`"> Report Generated at $(Get-Date)</H3>
                    <table BORDER=`"1`" CELLPADDING=`"5`" Align=`"Center`">
                    <tr> 
                        <td font-family: 'Calibri' BGColor=#98C6F3 Align=center><b>Server Name</b></td>
                        <td font-family: 'Calibri' BGColor=#98C6F3 Align=center><b>Online</b></td>
                        <td font-family: 'Calibri' BGColor=#98C6F3 Align=center><b>Uptime</b></td>
                    </tr>"

    }
}   
process {
    $Count=0
    $SuccessComps = 0
    $UnreachableComps = 0
    $FailedComps = 0
    $FinalOutput = @()
    foreach($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        $Count++
        $Computer = $Computer.Toupper()
        $OutputObj  = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer 
        $Status = 0
        if(Test-Connection -Computer $Computer -count 1 -ea 0) {
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsOnline -Value "TRUE"  
            try {
                $Boottime = (Get-WmiObject win32_operatingSystem -computer $Computer -ErrorAction stop).lastbootuptime
                $Boottime = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($BootTIme)
                $Now = Get-Date
                $span = New-TimeSpan $BootTime $Now 
                $Uptime = "{0} day(s), {1} hour(s), {2} min(s), {3} second(s)" -f $span.days, $span.hours, $span.minutes, $span.seconds
                $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime -Value $Uptime   
                $Status=1
                $SuccessComps++
            } catch {
                $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime -Value "FAILED TO GET" 
                $FailedComps++
            }

        } else {
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsOnline -Value "FALSE" 
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime -Value "" 

            $UnreachableComps++
        }

        $FinalOutput +=$OutputObj
        $OutputObj = $OutputObj 


        if($HTMLReport) {
            if($Status) {
                $BGColor="GreenYellow"
            } else {
                $BGColor="OrangeRed"
            }
            $IsOnline 
            $Report += " <TR>
                        <TD BGColor=$BGColor>$($OutputObj.ComputerName)</TD>
                        <TD BGColor=$BGColor>$($OutputObj.IsOnline)</TD>
                        <TD BGColor=$BGColor>$($OutputObj.Uptime)</TD> 
                        </TR>"

        } else {
            $OutputObj

        }

    }


}
end{
    if($HTMLReport) {
        $Report +=  
        $Report | Out-File $HTMLFile -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately, providing details on the errors receiving:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think Sort-Object will help you out.
$FinalOutput | Sort-Object IsOnline,uptime -descending

Version 2  you can put span field into

```
$FinalOutput | sort-Object IsOnline,span -descending | Select-Object ComputerName,IsOnline,Uptime
```

Comment: Thanks but this script still does not sort the uptime. it reports as 97 days, 10 days then 24 days. It looks like it is sorting the online column but not uptime I guess because it is caculating it

Comment: $FinalOutput | Sort-Object uptime, isonlin -Descending

Comment: Yes you can only short by one object as i see if False is empty then  Sort-Object uptime -Descending

Comment: Please share the output

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Keh6fXet     please see this link. I omitted the server names from the report

Comment: here is a screenshot of the output - https://imagebin.ca/v/3STGdLyHrn8O

Comment: Post your code with the shorting please i think i know where is the mistake.

Comment: I tried your code and it still does not sort the Uptime...thanks for trying though

Comment: Please share with me the $ShortOutPut  $FinalOutput  values.
Because it works when i do.

Comment: Run the script what i sent in powershell ISE and write out the two variables what i requested please.

Comment: PS C:\Temp> $ShortOutPut 

ComputerName IsOnline Uptime                                     
------------ -------- ------                                     
[removed)   ONLINE   40 day(s), 2 hour(s), 7 min(s), 5 second(s

Comment: PS C:\Temp> $FinalOutput 

ComputerName IsOnline Uptime                                               Ticks
------------ -------- ------                                               -----
[rempoved]   ONLINE   40 day(s), 2 hour(s), 7 min(s), 5 second(s) 34636254079192

Comment: Only one row in it?

Comment: the logic is bad how you call it will go line by line so it won't order just output the servers.
get-content servers.txt | ....

Comment: the only issue is the report shows OFFLINE as green (under Status column) can you make it red like it was before?

Comment: also dumping it to a HTML Report (-htmlreport switch) does not sort it when I run the command: PowerCLI C:\temp> Get-Content servers.txt | .\Get-UptimeOfServers-v1.ps1 -HTMLReport | Sort-object Uptime -descending

Comment: In the servers.txt there are server names line by line ?

Comment: i change the script is you need to call like this 
.\Get-UptimeOfServers-v1.ps1 -ComputerFile "C:\temp\Uptimereport.txt"
Uptimereport.txt the list of servers and in the script it will open txt read the files sortit etc...
Offline server red online green 
Code:
https://pastebin.com/QhsznKsL

Comment: works perfectly...thank you! what if I want to use a different account to authenticate with for querying the server uptime?

Comment: Windows scheduler you can run it with other user or you can insert
$Cred = Get-Credential before the the the foreach 
and
Test-Connection -Computer ... -Count 1 -Credential $Cred -Source Source server name

it will pop up a windows aouth window.